# Rails store categories in different languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, model

I'm building a multilang application that has two essential models **Category** and **Product**, where a **Category** has many **Products**..

So I want the ability to display the same categories with more than a language, for example, consider a category called Cars, it should be presented as **Vehicules** for a user using the french version of the application.

How could I do that? Should I store them in different models? or should I add a **lang** column in the **Category** model ?

What I thought of doing is adding a **lang** column in the Category model and add a *default_scope* call to scope it to search for only the desired language, I have two questions though:

1. How can I get the used language from inside a model, an I18n call ? Which method should I call on it ?
2. A problem arises from using this technique, a product which references a category in french wouldn't show up in a search under the category in english, how can I resolve this issue ?

Thank you

Comment: do you want sth like `I18n.t :carts, :locale => :fr` ?

Comment: something like that, but since categories are dynamic I can't just translate all possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Frankie Roberto* gave you a good answer. I will just add some additional info.

First the easy part: **getting current locale in a model**.

If you set the language in a controller as `I18n.locale = something`, then you may read it in a model the same way. The `I18n` is a global constant, after all.

**Now about searching**:

I generally prefer the designs where you have one category, but the name of the category is translated to many languages. The design where one car belongs to category "Cars" and another one belongs to "Vehicules" is flawed IMHO. In the later case there is no sense of making it a single site - you could create a one-language application, and install it in multiple instances, where every one is translated to a single language.

If you have a short, static list of supported languages, you may add a column for every language: `name_en`, `name_fr`, `name_pl`.

If your list of languages will be large or unknown at the moment of designing your application, it would be easier to store the "name" (given as an example) as a serialized hash. So, you could get the intended translation as `name["fr"]`, `name["de"]` and so on.

I have already learned *(the hard way :-) )* that users usually are too lazy to provide all the translations  *(or they just do not know all the languages)*, so you should be prepared that some of your models will **not** have the data in a language you are trying to display or search.

For every 'translated' attribute you may want to prepare a method which will supply you with the *most appropriate* translation in case the required one is missing.

This method may work in a way similar to:

```ruby
def translated_name
  ([I18n.locale] + other_languages).each do |l|
    return name[l] unless name[l].blank?
  end
  return "" # or some default value - possibly from I18n.t("some.static.default")
end
```

Of course, you do not need to use I18n.locale, and you should define `other_languages` in a way which would (ideally) match user language preferences, possibly by analyzing the "Accept-Language" header.

I sometimes use the method name `name_for(lang)` or `name_in(lang)`, if I have to support more languages for data than for interface (which I shall translate and put in I18n config files).

Ah, yes - searching. :)

If you have defined the "names" as separate attributes, you may just search the appropriate column.

If you have the "names" as a single, serialized hash, you may search the column as a simple text *(however I am not sure whether YAML will not mangle the non-ASCII characters)* or create another column with searchable data, and then *(at the model-level, not at the SQL level)* partition the models into groups: "The search string has been found in your language", "The search string has been found in some other language". I believe the user of multi-lang service will be happy with search results presented in this way.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I think I will use some of your ideas combined with the ideas behind puret gem, for instance it would be easier searching a join model than a YAML column yet more customizable using my own logic of replacing missing translations (or just patch puret to be more customizable :) )... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The key question you have to ask yourself is whether it's important that the Cars category should be the same object (implying the same object and the same URL) as the Vehicules category or not.

If they should be the same category, then the only question is how you translate the name into different languages. If you have a relatively small number of languages to support, you could simply store them all on the model using different columns (`name_en`, `name_fr`, etc).

Or you could store the translated names separately, such as using the `I18n` modules.

Alternatively, if Cars and Vehicules are separate categories, then you could follow your suggestion of adding a `lang` attribute to the model.

Comment: +1 for the part about using columns for translated names. It's the simplest and most reliable solution - if the user is creating categories, then only the user may be able to reliably translate them.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this gem to solve this kind of problem: https://github.com/jo/puret

Comment: Perhaps you could give a brief overview of how that gem helps solve the problem?